# Jade: Ignore spaces in mixin arguments to align code?

Tags: optimization, alignment, pug, code-cleanup

I'd like to align elements of my code for easier reading, but ignore the extra spaces on compile. For example, I'd like to convert:

```
+navOption('biography', 'Biography and Timeline')
+navOption('books-articles', 'Books and Articles about Paul Rand')
+navOption('events-exhibits', 'Events and Exhibits')
+navOption('videos-interviews', 'Videos and Interview')
+navOption('portraits', 'Portraits')
+navOption('rand-house', 'The Rand House')
+navOption('his-inspirations', 'Inspirations')
+navOption('personal-items', 'Personal Items')
+navOption('death', 'Death')
```

to:

```
+navOption('biography        ', 'Biography and Timeline            ')
+navOption('books-articles   ', 'Books and Articles about Paul Rand')
+navOption('events-exhibits  ', 'Events and Exhibits               ')
+navOption('videos-interviews', 'Videos and Interview              ')
+navOption('portraits        ', 'Portraits                         ')
+navOption('rand-house       ', 'The Rand House                    ')
+navOption('his-inspirations ', 'Inspirations                      ')
+navOption('personal-items   ', 'Personal Items                    ')
+navOption('death            ', 'Death                             ')
```

Is there a way to ignore the extra spaces created between the last letter/number/symbol of the argument and the closing apostrophe?

Comment: I do the same but instead of putting spaces *in* the quotes I just put them outside. I.e. instead of `'biography        ',` I do `'biography'        ,`

Comment: Ah! Brilliant! I'll try that. Thank you!